How would I create an extension that adds a tab to a core afform?
I'm following up on the questions about embedding javascript in an angular form (FormBuilder: alterAngular embed javascript), but specifically to do so with a core afform.
I'm trying to build an extension that allows people to choose the drupal theme they want to use when displaying a public afform.
Using hook_civicrm_alterAngular() I can easily insert the field to select the theme. But, I can't save the setting. Or to be more precise, I did manage to get the setting saved using "onchange" and some jquery code. But I couldn't get the field to display the current value for the theme. I think angular is somehow interfering with jquery when I try to update a value on the form (probably for the reasons coleman explains in the above answer).
@coleman suggests overriding the form with a local copy, but I'm hesitant to do that for fear of diverging from any changes during an upgrade.
I also tried using @demerit's trick (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31264/181). But given coleman's warning about caching it didn't seem viable.
I also tried shoving the angular code directly into the hook_civicrm_alterAngular call via the  tag, but that didn't seem to work because angularjs complained about the controller not being defined. I think it processed the form before the javascript code.
So that's how I ended up with this question: Can I create an angular app that adds a new tab to the core afform form. There's a "+" button that lists all the things that can be added as tabs. Is there a way I can add my own?
Thanks!

At last. I figured out the more proper angular method for adding a new field to a core angular form and saving the data entered in the field.

Add an angular module to your extension: civix generate:angular-module
Add your new field via hook_civicrm_alterAngular():

function dynamic_theme_selector_civicrm_alterAngular($angular) {                                                                                              
  $angular->add(\Civi\Angular\ChangeSet::create('dts_theme_field')                                                                                        
    ->alterHtml('~/afGuiEditor/config-form.html', function(phpQueryObject $doc) {                                                                                                                                   
      $element = <<<END                                                                                     
      <div class="form-group" ng-if="editor.afform.is_public" ng-controller="dtsThemeCtrl">                                                                                                        
        <label for="af_theme">{{ ts('Select a theme') }}</label>                                           
        <div class="input-group">                                                                                                              
          <select id="af_theme"                                                                                                                          
            ng-model="af_theme"                                                                                                                      
            name="af_theme"                                                                                                                                                                 
            class="form-control"                                                                                                                                                              
            title="{{ ts('Select a theme') }}"                                                             
            ng-options="theme for theme in af_theme_options"                                                                                                 
            ng-change="save_theme()"                                                                                                                                   
          >                                                                                                                                                        
          </select>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        </div>                                                                                                       
        <p class="help-block">Enter the theme you would like to use to display this form.</p>                                                                                                               
      </div>                                                                                               
END;                                                                                                                                              
      $doc->append($element);                                                                                                                               
    })                                                                                                                                                  
  );                                                                                                                                                                                            
}   

Important things to note in the code snippet above:

~/afGuiEditor/config-form.html is the core angular form I'm modifying
dtsThemeCtrl is the name of the controller that I will referencing.
af_theme is the name of the model that I will be saving.


Ensure the core form you are modifying requires your angular module via hook_civicrm_angularModules:

function dynamic_theme_selector_civicrm_angularModules(&$angularModules) {                                                                              
  $angularModules['afGuiEditor']['requires'][] = 'crmDynamicThemeSelector';                                                                                                                     
}


Edit the angular module created in step one (in my case, ang/crmDynamicThemeSelector.js):

(function(angular, $, _) {                                                              
  angular.module('crmDynamicThemeSelector', CRM.angRequires('crmDynamicThemeSelector'));
  // Our only purpose is to extend the afGuidEditor so we can control the
  // theme field we insert via hook_civicrm_alterAngular.                             
  try {
    angular.module('afGuiEditor').controller('dtsThemeCtrl', function($scope, crmApi4) {
      $scope.af_theme_options = [];
                              
      $scope.init = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                       
        crmApi4('Setting', 'get', {                                                                                                                                                                                    
          // Get all possible customized formbuilder themes.                                                                                                                                                           
          select: ["dynamic_theme_selector_chosen_formbuilder_themes"]                                                                                                                                                 
        }).then(function(chosen_themes) {                                                                                                                                                                              
          var route = $scope.editor.afform.server_route;                                                                                                                                                               
          var chosen_theme = '';                                                                                                                                                                                       
          if (chosen_themes[0]['value'][route]) {                                                                                                                                                                      
            chosen_theme = chosen_themes[0]['value'][route];                                                                                                                                                           
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          $scope.af_theme = chosen_theme;                                                                                                                                                                              
          // Get available themes to populate the drop down.                                                                                                                                                           
          return crmApi4('Dts', 'GetAvailableThemes', {});                                                                                                                                                             
        }).then(function(result) {                                                                                                                                                                                     
          Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {                                                                                                                                                           
            $scope.af_theme_options.push(key);                                                                                                                                                                         
          });                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      };                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      $scope.save_theme = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        var route = $scope.editor.afform.server_route;                                                                                                                                                                 
        console.log("Updating route -> theme", route, $scope.af_theme);                                                                                                                                                
        CRM.api4('Dts', 'UpdateSelectedTheme', {                                                                                                                                                                       
          'entity': 'formbuilder',                                                                                                                                                                                     
          'theme': $scope.af_theme,                                                                                                                                                                                    
          'id': route                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      };                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      $scope.init();                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error registered", err);
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
})(angular, CRM.$, CRM._);  

Important things to note in the snippet above:

angular.module('afGuiEditor') references the angular module I'm modifying (it's the first part of the first argument passed to alterHtml above).
controller('dtsThemeCtrl' refers to the controller I named in the html snippet above.
$scope.af_theme is how I access the value of my field because I used ng-model="af_theme"


Well done Jamie!

Well, it feels really hacky and 2010, but I managed to get it to work using hook_civicrm_pageRun. My field exists entirely outside of angular and is controlled via jquery. Hopefully there is a better answer using angularjs, but this works as a hack.
